# how we can assign shortcut to frequently used command in eclipse (for example Run as Android Application or override/implements method)

Tags: android, eclipse, shortcut

i am android developer using Eclipse to develop android application. i want to know is there any way to assign keyboard shortcuts to frequently used commands in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Eclipse >> preferences >> General >> Keys

Now select your command(Operation you wants to perform)

Focus to Binding and press your desired keys from keyboard.

And you will be done.